# Magento 2 with aws-s3 remote storage of images - tutorial?

Tags: magento2, aws, s3

I'm currently trying to configure Magento 2.4.3 with AWS s3 for storing media. The [guide on the Magento website](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/remote-storage/config-remote-storage-aws-s3.html) is lacking in a lot of detail, I think. For example, it implies you can use AWS IAM to configure s3 storage and not require the use of the [ngx_aws_auth](https://github.com/anomalizer/ngx_aws_auth) module, which seems it's no longer developed. However, there's nothing telling you how to do this.

Has anyone successfully managed to configure the native `aws-s3` storage along with nginx? I'm getting random errors such as being shown the 503 error page, with Magento thinking it's in maintenance mode for some reason (the flag isn't there, removing the relevant aws-s3 section from `env.php` removes the issue).

If anyone has a guide they can point me to, or walk through the steps they've taken, that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested with a CloudFront URL in front of my S3.

1. Disable DB storage (disabled by default)

```
magento config:set system/media_storage_configuration/media_database 0
```

2. Configure AWS-S3

```
magento setup:config:set \
    --remote-storage-driver="aws-s3" \
    --remote-storage-bucket="UNIQUE-BUCKET-NAME" \
    --remote-storage-prefix="myPREFIX" \
    --remote-storage-region="me-south-X" \
    --remote-storage-key="REMOTE_STORAGE_KEY" \
    --remote-storage-secret="REMOTE_STORAGE_SECRET"
```

3. Configure CDN URL

```
magento config:set web/unsecure/base_media_url "https://WHATEVER.cloudfront.net/myPREFIX/media/"
magento config:set web/secure/base_media_url "https://WHATEVER.cloudfront.net/myPREFIX/media/"
```

4. Migrate Content (in 2.4.3, you can only run this once!)

```
magento remote-storage:sync
```

Comment: Thanks. Did you have to do any special setup in the AWS account IAM role or did you use the ngx_aws_auth module?

Comment: @fistameeny - as far as I'm aware, the [`aws-s3` driver does not support encryption algorithm to encrypt files with on upload](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34782). So you must disable [`sse-s3`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingServerSideEncryption.html) or [`sse-kms`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingKMSEncryption.html)